# installing clojure on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, clojure, installation, instructions

I hope you can help me.

I am taking a class on Artificial Intelligence and I'm required to install Clojure on my laptop. I have a macbook pro and I am having a tough time trying to make sure I have installed everything correctly, and is Terminal the only environment I can work on.

1. I downloaded Java JDK, also the patchwork for Java to work on El Capitan from the Apple website, and finally the Clojure pack from clojure.org's site.
2. Are we supposed to work from our terminal or is there an environment like Xamarin studio that I should work from.

Our instructor only had the information for windows laptops not mac's or Linux's. So we're struggling to find a solution.

Comment: Your second question may be a separate discussion altogether. That is up to your instructor.

Answer (score 5):

You can install Leiningen with brew like this:

brew install leiningen

And then learn how to use it here: [Leiningen Tutorial](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/TUTORIAL.md)

Answer (score 2):

For #1, Leiningen is the de-facto build tool in the clojure world. It is really easy to install. Check out the instructions right on the home [page](http://leiningen.org/). Once you have that installed, the easiest and fastest way to get going is to fire up the lein repl with:

```
lein repl
```

This gives a clojure REPL where you can start to try out clojure.

For #2, If you are doing school work, I would recommend the non-commercial license version of [cursiveclojure](https://cursive-ide.com/) as an IDE. [lighttable](http://lighttable.com/) in another good option.

Comment: Thanks for the the IDE suggestions!